# How to get the UPerfect portable monitor to work with a computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-supply

I've connected it to my laptop but when I turn up the brightness more than 50% using the on screen display the monitor powers off and I cannot turn it on again.

As soon as I turn on the monitor it switches off before I can reduce the brightness. It becomes useless because I cannot change it.

I noticed if I wait a day or two then when I connect it again it appears to work but it is at low brightness.

I have power connected to USB C on the left side and monitor is connected to macbook on USB C on the left side. I am using supplied cables and supplied power supply and it is plugged into a surge protector.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the power supply that comes with the monitor is underpowered.

When the laptop is connected it sends out a 4k signal. The power supply supplied is 35W. The monitor with a 4k signal requires more power than that.

The solution I found is to use the laptop power supply to power the monitor and then connect the laptop to the monitor.

How to:

1. plug in a high powered power supply like magsafe 60w or 75w into a wall socket or power supply
2. connect that the power supply with the white USB C cord to the monitor left side USB C port (NOT THE RIGHT SIDE)
3. next, connect the heavy black USB C cord that came with the monitor to the monitor left side USB C port (NOT THE RIGHT SIDE) and then connect that to the laptop USB C port

If that doesn't work unplug the cords and then hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds until the red light goes off or dark and then reconnect the cables again.

Alternatively, keep the brightness level below 50% or use the mini HDMI to normal HDMI cable to plugin into a USB-C hub with HDMI out (you may still need a 60W power supply).

**NOTE**

- The ports matter. Make sure they are powered. On the model I have they are on the left side.
- The USB C cables matter. Use the laptop and supplied USB C from the monitor.
- Do not use the supplied power supply. The one supplied with the laptop is too low powered. Use the laptop power supply 60W or higher (you can try 45W I don't have one).

**NOTES on the monitor**

- Have a physical button to open the OSD (even when no signal)
- Show a light on the device when a fully adequate power source is connected
- If full power is not available and too much power is drawn, then reduce brightness (currently monitor switches off with no option to change it)
- Have a physical reset button
- Do not have a USB C port that does accept power (or have physical label on plug "Not power")
- Have option to turn off touch screen
- Have USB to mini HDMI cable so you can hook up USB C device to mini HDMI port of the monitor
- If special USB C cables are needed add labels to them. "Connect to Power" and "Connect to device"
- Make sure the OSD displays even with no signal connection
- Show when full power is active in OSD
- Optionally, include a full power supply